# Запуск тестов в разных браузерах одновременно

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

Как запустить один и тот же тест в нескольких браузерах одновременно?

Пытался использовать Selenium grid, но не хватило знаний и навыков гугления.

Запускаю на своей машине Windows 8.1
Использую JUnit Webdriver 2.0 maven

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ответы не помогли я сам справился

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параллельный запуск тестов является одним из мощных средств для ускорения тестирования. Хорошо автоматизированные тесты должны быть независимыми, изолированными и воспроизводимыми, эти качества делают их идеальными для одновременного выполнения. Однако на практике не все тестовые классы разработаны с возможностью параллельного запуска. Такие аспекты, как общие изменяемые переменные, общий доступ к файлу и базе данных, или использование встроенного веб-сервера, могут сделать параллельный запуск тестов очень сложным или вообще невозможным. Тем не менее, одновременный запуск тестов, определенно, очень полезная вещь.

Начиная с версии `4.7` в `JUnit` была добавлена возможность параллельного запуска, для этого нужно настроить Maven следующим образом:

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>methods</parallel>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

Атрибут `parallel` может принимать значения «classes», «methods» или «both». При этом нельзя однозначно утверждать о количестве запущенных одновременно тестов, это напрямую зависит от параметров компьютера и настроек плагина по-умолчанию.

Во время запуска теста найдите следующую строку в консоли, она позволяет узнать параметры с которыми выполняется параллельный запуск:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='methods', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, 
useUnlimitedThreads=false
```

Атрибут `threadCount` позволяет указать, сколько потоков должно быть выделено для запуска тестов (сколько тестов должно запускаться параллельно). Обратите внимание, что его использование с параметром `perCoreThreadCount`, установленным в `true`, может исказить реальное количество запускаемых одновременно тестов. В то же время `perCoreThreadCount` позволяет добиться большей гибкости при запуске тестов на разных машинах. Например, при запуске тестов со следующей конфигурацией на машине с 2-х ядерным процессором, одновременно будут выполняться 4 тестовых класса, а не 2:

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>classes</parallel>
          <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
          <threadCount>2</threadCount>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

Существует еще такой атрибут как `useUnlimitedThreads`. При его использовании будет создаваться столько потоков, сколько классов или методов в Вашем проекте, и все тесты будут пытаться запуститься одновременно. `useUnlimitedThreads` отлично работает для юнит-тестов, но для функционального web тестирования его лучше не использовать.

Настройки конфигурации полностью зависят от характера Ваших тестов, поэтому стоит поэкспериментировать с различными конфигурациями и посмотреть, какой из вариантов настройки больше всего подходит для Вас.

Информация взята с 
[Блога вебразработчика](http://internetka.in.ua)

В будущем советую все таки использовать [Google](http://www.google.com). И не бояться эксперементировать со своим проектом. Надеюсь предоставленная информация Вам поможет, удачи в дальнейших трудах)

Comment: Я читал эту статью. Это немного не то. У меня задача запустить один и тот же тест в разных браузерах. Писать для каждого браузера тест кейс, а потом запускать их смахивает на копипасту. Я думал получить тут совет как правильно настроить Selenium grid что бы это потом происходило в один клик.

Comment: [Вот тут](http://automated-testing.info/t/selenium-2-0-parallelnyj-zapusk-testov/1541) тоже возможно поискать ответы. Но нет гарантии, что такой запуск тестов даст стабильный результат, к сожалению.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: завел чат про тестирование, заходите http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29159/software-quality-assurance-and-testing-russian

Comment: предлагаю тут потереть обсуждение, все-таки оно не по теме.